# Difference in ApplicationContextProvider.getContext() and class.forName()?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

When to use ApplicationContextProvider.getContext() over class.forName() ?

Difference between  ApplicationContextProvider.getContext() over class.forName() and @Autowired()
all this can be used to get the instance of the class but when to choose  them in a ideal scenario in real time application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Class.forName(String name)` method returns the Class object associated with the class or interface with the given string name.

The `ApplicationContextProvider.getContext()` method returns Spring Application Context which can help you to get an initialized bean from spring context.

Comment: Class.forName(String name) returns class obj, but  ApplicationContextProvider.getContext() returns class obj from spring context. So what is the difference ? class obj and beans both  are they both same ?

Comment: No, class obj and beans are not the same. Class obj is the representation of your class as obj and bean is an initialized object(instance from your class) in spring context.

Comment: Class.forName(String name) used when I need to create a class obj which is not there in spring context And ApplicationContextProvider.getContext() is used when object is initialized in the spring context, am I right ? 
And in class object we don't create new instance of class instead just get the reference of class, but in case of bean, we will get instance reference form spring context  right ? If I am wrong please give some example for object and bean ?
Thank you soo much !!

Comment: Yeah, you can clearly understand it by the documentation of Class.forName(String name).newInstance() method here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance-- and ApplicationContextProvider.getContext().getBean(Class) method here https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.Class-